# Is it possible to increment/decrement a value in a DataRow using C#'s operators?

Tags: c#

It looks like it's only possible to increment a value by saying:

```
DataRow someRow = GetRow();
someRow[0] = someRow[0] + 10;
```

Is there any way to perform this operation in C#? I can't seem to find anything...I'm assuming this is because a [DataRow.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an object.

```
DataRow someRow = GetRow();
someRow[0] += 10;
someRow[0] -= 10;
someRow[0] *= 5;
```

Comment: Are you sure this `someRow[0] + 10` works?

Comment: ".I'm assuming this is because a DataRow.Item returns an object." - yes.   The column could have a string value to, so `+= 10` would not be valid.

Comment: Only thing that would compile is `someRow[0] = (int)someRow[0] + 10;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to perform this operation in C#?

No, you have first to cast or convert the `someRow[0]` to the corresponding type and then you can use addition, multiplication, etc.

The following would result in a compilation error:

```
someRow[0] = someRow[0] + 10;
```

since `someRow[0]`'s type is `Object` while 10 is an integer literal.

The correct approach would be something like the following:

```
someRow[0] = (int)someRow[0] + 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use the TryParse method in c#, and check if the returned object is actually an integer and then perform the required operation.

Like:

```
int temp;
Int64.TryParse((String)someRow[0], out temp);
someRow[0] = temp + 10;
```

You could convert the onject to int by simply casting it: (int)someRow[0] or using ConvertTo methods, but the above is least prone to errors.